# PHP_CSV_Utilities Cannot find CSV_Reader Class

Tags: php, csv, utilities

Does anyone have experience with the PHP CSV Utilities library ( http://code.google.com/p/php-csv-utils/wiki/Documentation )? I've tried to install it on my Mac--I'm running XAMPP and editing with Aptana 3. I followed the instructions and copied the CSV folder over to my project file so the organization looks like this:

- xamppfiles

  - htdocs
  - MyFirstPHP

    - Csv
    - Reader.php
    - AutoDetect.php
    - Exception.php (and so on)
  - index.php

(xampp files contains folder htdocs, which contains folder MyFirstPHP that contains the index.php file and the CSV folder with Reader.php, AutoDetect.php, Exception.php, etc.)
When I go to create a new class of CSV_Reader, Aptana recognizes the new class and helps me create it, but when I run it in my browser I get a fatal error. I also tried a require_once like so:

```
require_once 'Reader.php';
```

I also tried requiring all of the included files (AutoDetect.php, Exception.php, etc.). Did I install the library in the wrong location? I've searched through a ton of Google documentation and blogs, but have yet to find a way to make this work successfully.

Comment: you  might want to check your php.ini settings especially include_path. Also you might want to post the results as part of your questions if the problem persists.

Comment: The following was my include path:
include_path=".:/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/php:/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/php/pear"

Warning: require_once(Reader.php) [function.require-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/MyFirstPHP/index.php on line 19
Here is the error:
Fatal error: require_once() [function.require]: Failed opening required 'Reader.php' (include_path='.:/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/php:/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/php/pear') in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/MyFirstPHP/index.php on line 19

Comment: Sorry for the poor formatting, this was the error:
Warning: require_once(Reader.php) [function.require-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/MyFirstPHP/index.php on line 19

Fatal error: require_once() [function.require]: Failed opening required 'Reader.php' (include_path='.:/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/php:/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/php/pear') in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/MyFirstPHP/index.php on line 19

Comment: /Applications might have the wrong permissions. Please check by moving the Library to a directory in your home path and checking/setting the permisson.